Adjusting rig setup over a shape key
This seems to be a tough one. Say I have a human rigged 3D model that, with a shape key, transforms into a werewolf. And so bigger, with different proportions (longer arms and legs etc.).
There is a way to have the rig adjust to the shape key transformation automatically? Drivers to the opposite thing, and I really don't know how to do it... Thanks for any help.

Simpler solution is to have two different rigs triggering two different characters, turning on and off one of them when necessary.
Another way is to have two rigs on the same character, driving two different armature modifiers, turning on and off their influence sliders when necessary.
Any solution involving a coded variation of the rest pose I think it would become a nightmare during the animation process.

Hi Josh thanks for the suggestions. I think suggestion nr.2 would be the most effective because I need the character to morph and animate at the same time. Although, managing two different control rigs at the same time might be problematic.
Anyway, odd that Blender doesn't actually support a dynamic rig system so that bones can actually change shape and location (not pose) using a driver, just as it happens with shape keys.
